# Getting null value in struts 2 action when called using ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jquery, struts2

I am trying to send a form data to a struts2 action through ajax call. 
I have gone through many posts in stackoverflow as well as other tutorial.
Even though I am following all the steps properly , I am getting null values in action method.

Please help me to resolve the issue. This post might be a duplicate one, but I have not found proper answer in any of the old posts.

JSP Code

```
 <script  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $(document).ready(function() {
 var dataObj = $("#dForm").serialize();
 $("#submitdata").click(function(){
        $.ajax( {
          traditional: true,
          type: "POST",      
          url: "data/postData",
          contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          async: false,
          data : dataObj,
          success: function(response) {
                alert("success "+response);
          },
          error: function(e) { 
                alert("error "+e.Message);
          }
        });
    }); 
  </script>

  <s:form name="dataform" id ="dForm" method="post">
    <s:textarea id="data" name="data" class="data" rows="4" cols="100" />
    <s:submit  type="submit" value="submit" id="submitdata" />
</s:form>
```

Action Class

```
  public class DataAction {
     String data;

        public String getData() {
            return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
      this.data = data;
    }

        public String postData() {
          System.out.println("** postData called *** "+getData());
          //Here getData always return null.
          return "Success";
        }
  }
```

Struts.xml

```
   <package name="Data" extends="json-default" namespace="data">
    <action name="postData" class="com.data.action.DataAction"
        method="postData">
        <result type="json"></result>
    </action>
   </package>
```

What else has to be done ?
Also When I set async: true in ajax, action method never getting called.
Ok my primary concern is why Data is null ?

when I do the same without ajax , it works perfectly.

Please help....

Comment: You can see the request when using something like firebug or the chrome dev tools.. Can you post it here?

Comment: I think its not correct. Am getting it as /myAppName/Views and method type as POSt . I saw it in chrome dev tool under network tab. But if post method is not correct then how come action method is getting called ? also I saw it at the time when an alert is shown which has been put under error case of ajax . Because once the we get the response immediately other page is loaded we can not catch the request in network tab.

Comment: It is resolved - the problem is in $(document).ready(function() { } method. var dataObj = $("#dForm").serialize(); has to be placed within  .click() method.. but it is not working when extends="json-default" in struts.xml . its working with "struts.default" . if "json-default" action method not even getting called.

Comment: Now I can successfully call action method and am getting proper data from the UI to action class. But after executing web services successfully it always goes to error block in ajax even the response is success. please check below comment of mine for the error i am getting in console.